# Is it possible to talk with the users of my Facebook app through Facebook chat?

Tags: facebook, browser, chat

If I create a browser based Facebook app is it possible to talk, using Facebook chat, with the users that use my app? Is there any kind of users list that used the app like the normal friends list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are unable to do this.  The only way would be to friend the users and then use the chat.  Technically your app is not sentient and therefore unable to "chat".  An alternative for you might be to request the users email address from permissions and then contact them using this.

Comment: Hm ok, email request it is. Thanks for your answer!